# Angular mat-error not taking up its own space

Tags: css, angular-material

I have a form with mat-errors that I'm trying to space out. I know I can simply space out the form fields themselves, but I've been trying to add margin/padding/border to `mat-error` elements, and they all get applied, but they don't move.

[image]

As far as the CSS goes, I've tried most things I can think of to force it to move. The styles are applied but nothing is actually changing.

```
  mat-error{
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important;
    margin-bottom: 40px !important;
    padding-bottom: 40px !important;
    z-index: 999;
  }
```

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your css to class: `.mat-error` instead of `mat-error`.
2. In order to change styles in angular materials you should define a global stylesheet declared in the styles array of your angular.json configuration file. and custom all mat styles within.

In Styles.css:

```css
.mat-error {
    color: aqua;
}
```

The result will be:

[image: Custom mat-error style]

Please read [Customizing Angular Material component styles](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles) article for better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's a kluge, but I was able to do it by increasing the margins and padding of these classes:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  margin: 0.25em 0 1.2em 0 !important;
}
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
  padding: 0 0.5em !important;
}
```